# Nodejs/Express clickable image on the form

Tags: node.js, image, express, post, form-submit

I have an image on the form in NodeJs/Express app. I want it act as submit type button.

```
<form id="form_nav1" action="/about" method="post">  
    <div>
        <img src="/images/aboutus.png" type="submit" style="cursor:pointer;" name="about_us">
    </div>
</form>
```

I am expecting a POST call to index.js but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit buttons are submit buttons, images are images. You can't put a `type` attribute on an arbitrary element.

Create a submit button containing an image:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Form submitted");
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com">
  <button name="about_us" value="submit">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/50" alt="About Us">
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also put a click listener on your image and do the post request with javascript